# Remove a commit from a branch and put it on a separate branch

Tags: git, branch

My project has a single branch `master`. Let's say I've performed four commits `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Now I just realized that `D` is something that is too experimental, so it should not be on `master` (yet), but rather on a separate branch of its own, say `experimental`.

How do I:

- Put `D` on a branch of its own?
- Go back to `C` as `master` and perform new commits on this branch?

(Note: I don't want to just undo the commit)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can move a commit, but you can just [undo the commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit), switch branches, and commit again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to [`branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) the `experimental` branch from `master`:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/myproject [master] $ git branch experimental
```

Then, you can [`reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) the `master` branch to one commit behind:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/myproject [master] $ git reset HEAD~ --hard
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create the `experimental` branch on the `D` commit. At this point it will be the same as `master`.

Do a `git checkout master`.

Do a `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. (This gets you on commit `C`)
Now do a `push -f` (from the master branch. this will push `C` as last commit on `master`).

This should solve it.